# Chrome Incognito session cookie location?

Tags: google-chrome, security, cookies

What is the location of Chromes Incognito cookies while Incognito is active?

We know the location for regular cookies in Chrome for Windows 7 is at:

```
c:\user\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default\
```

But, where are the cookies kept when Incognito mode is active?
I want to know for security purposes, so I can protect those better by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure it's exactly where you just specified. You can open the Resource Monitor tool, go to disk, sort the image column under the disk activity section, then open an incognito session and go to any website. You should see a few lines of your harddrive writing data to ...\chrome\user data\default\